# Consulta a partir de la fecha actual del sistema

Tags: sql, sql-server

Como consultar a partir de la fecha actual del sistema sin tener que especificar lo siguiente

```
 fechaEntrada BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2017-11-01 00:00:00',121) and 
                    CONVERT(DATETIME,'2017-11-01 23:59:59',121
```

La consulta:

```
select c.CodeCompany,
        CONVERT(char(6), GETDATE(), 112) AS fechaActual,
        a.idClave,
        c.nombre + ' ' + c.apellidos as Nombre,
        d.Descripcion as Depto, 
        CONVERT (date, GETDATE()) fechaEntrada,
        CONVERT (date, GETDATE()) fechaSalida,
       DATEDIFF(HOUR, fechaEntrada, fechaSalida) %24 AS horasAlDia


            from tblasistencia a JOIN tblpersonal c ON a.idClave=c.idClave
                 JOIN tblDepto d ON c.fkDepto=d.idDepto

             where 
                fechaEntrada BETWEEN CONVERT (time, SYSDATETIME('00:00:00')) and 
                CONVERT (time, SYSDATETIME('23:59:59'))
```

Esto es incorrecto por que SYSDATETIME No recibe argumentos; sin embargo la consulta debe
tomar los registros a parti de las 00:00:00 hasta las 23:59:59 del día o la fecha actual

Comment: En la primera consulta consideras desde '2017-11-01 00:00:00' hasta '2017-11-30 23:59:59' (un mes), pero líneas abajo dices que prefieres solo para la fecha actual. ¿Es para un mes o un día?

Comment: Estoy confundido. ¿Qué es `fechaEntrada` en tu consulta? Porque no lo usas de forma legal. ¿Es una columna, o un valor calculado?

Comment: Es para 1 día y fechaEntrada es una columna

Answer (score 2):

Tu consulta es un poco rara en cómo usa `fechaEntrada`. Por un lado, parece una columna calculada, pero por otro, lo usas como si fuera una columna de una tabla.

Para contestar la pregunta, voy a asumir que `fechaEntrada` es simplemente una columna normal. Y como tu consulta necesita filtrar por esa columna, lo normal y razonable es que hayas definido un índice en esa columna para mejor rendimiento.

Con esto en mente, la técnica que equilibra mejor exactitud, sencillez y buen rendimiento (si hay un índice definido, lo va a aprovechar) es, en mi opinión, la siguiente:

```
declare @Hoy datetime = cast(getdate() as date);

select *
  from tbl
 where fechaEntrada >= @Hoy     -- condición inclusiva
   and fechaEntrada < @Hoy + 1  -- condición exclusiva
```

Estoy al tanto que muchos se empeñan en querer usar el `BETWEEN` en vez de dividir la condición en 2 como yo lo hago. Tal vez lo hacen pensando que debe ser más eficiente expresar el filtro usando una sola expresión en vez de 2, pero esto no es cierto.

Pero como has notado, aunque su rendimiento es bueno, la inconveniencia es que `BETWEEN` evalúa ambas fechas límites de forma inclusiva, lo que te obliga a agregar el `23:59:59` de forma artificial a la segunda fecha para obtener los resultados deseados, lo que en mi opinión es feíto e incómodo, pero además, técnicamente no es 100% exacto.  Por ejemplo, ¿qué sucedería si hubiera una fecha `2017-12-22 23:59:59.500` con fracciones de segundo, lo que es posible con el tipo `datetime`?

Luego, también existen otras opciones (como las que encuentras en las otras respuestas) que definitivamente son válidas, y hasta se puede decir elegantes, pero requieren que incluyas la columna `fechaEntrada` en una llamada a una función, como `CONVERT` o `DATEDIFF`. Por más atractivas que son estas opciones, estas no son ideales para el rendimiento de tu consulta. Si tienes un índice definido en la columna `fechaEntrada` (lo que sería una buena idea), estas consultas no pueden aprovechar el índice para mejorar el rendimiento de la consulta.

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que lo que buscas es seleccionar sobre una columna con información de fecha y hora la información que corresponde al día en curso. Si efectivamente es así, lo que te sugiero en primer lugar manejar una variable de fecha que la completaremos con `GETDATE()`, hacemos esto ya que `GETDATE()` es una función no deterministica, es decir siempre que la llamemos traera una fecha+hora distinta, por lo que siempre es mejor trabajar con una variable inicializada al comienzo, veamos:

```
DECLARE @Hoy DATETIME

SELECT  @Hoy = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112))

select c.CodeCompany,
       CONVERT(char(6), @Hoy, 112) AS fechaActual,
       a.idClave,
       c.nombre + ' ' + c.apellidos as Nombre,
       d.Descripcion as Depto, 
       CONVERT (date, @Hoy) fechaEntrada,
       CONVERT (date, @Hoy) fechaSalida,
       DATEDIFF(HOUR, fechaEntrada, fechaSalida) %24 AS horasAlDia
       from tblasistencia a JOIN tblpersonal c ON a.idClave=c.idClave
       JOIN tblDepto d ON c.fkDepto=d.idDepto
       where 
           CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, fechaEntrada, 112)) = @Hoy
```

El truco es convertir tanto la fecha actual como la de la tabla en fechas sin la parte de hora, haciendo `CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, fechaEntrada, 112))` y recién comparar ambas.

Comment: ¿Cómo podria especificar que tome los valores del día actual desde las 00:00:00 hasta las 23:59:59?

Comment: @NetzaL, es que no necesitas hacer eso, mi respuesta justamente apunta a comparar dos `DATETIME` a los que le quitamos la parte horaria, de esta forma no importa si `fechaEntrada` es `20171226 00:00:01' o `20171226 23:59:59`, terminaremos comparando solo la fecha.

Comment: Con la consulta anterior, me devuelve el resultado asi:
CodeCompany      fechaActual Clave                       Nombre               Depto                       Entrada                  Salida                  SumaHoras
2300  201712  8206  USER1  TT                          2017-12-26 2017-12-26 8

Comment: También debido a que en la consulta se encuentra especificado de esta forma:
    CONVERT (date, @Hoy) fechaEntrada,
       CONVERT (date, @Hoy) fechaSalida
Lo correcto serìa de esta forma (especificando la hora de entrada, y hora de salida)
CodeCompany      fechaActual Clave                       Nombre               Depto                       Entrada                  Salida                  SumaHoras

2300  201712  8206  USER1  TT                          8:12:00                   17:34:00 8

Comment: Ahora si te entiendo, puedes formatear la `fechaEntrada` de la siguiente forma `CONVERT(VARCHAR, @Hoy, 121)` debería mostrarte `2017-12-26 00:00:00 000`, para la `fechaSalida`, podrías hacer `CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(ss, 23*3600+59*60+59, @Hoy), 121)`

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres considerar solo fechas que tengan el mismo día pero sin las horas, podrías hacer uso de `DATEDIFF`.

Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT
    DATEDIFF(DD, '20171223 03:29:03', '20171223 03:29:03')
    ,DATEDIFF(DD, '20171224 03:29:03', '20171223 03:29:03')
    ,DATEDIFF(DD, '20171222 03:29:03', '20171223 03:29:03')
    ,DATEDIFF(DD, '20171223 23:59:59', '20171223 03:29:03')
```

Se obtiene:

> ```
> +------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
> | (No column name) | (No column name) | (No column name) | (No column name) |
> +------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
> |                0 |               -1 |                1 |                0 |
> +------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
> ```

[**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/JBK22521)

---

En tu caso si quieres para la fecha actual, podrías considerar:

```
where DATEDIFF(DD, fechaEntrada, GETDATE()) = 0
```

---

**Referencia:**

- [DATEDIFF Transact-SQL](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql)